# Recursion on a list in Scheme - avoid premature termination

Tags: recursion, scheme

I was doing a problem from the HTDP book where you have to create a function that finds all the permutations for the list. The book gives the main function, and the question asks for you to create the helper function that would insert an element everywhere in the list. The helper function, called `insert_everywhere`, is only given 2 parameters.

No matter how hard I try, I can't seem to create this function using only two parameters.

This is my code:

```
(define (insert_everywhere elt lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty]
    [else (append (cons elt lst) 
                  (cons (first lst) (insert_everywhere elt (rest lst))))]))
```

My desired output for `(insert_everywhere 'a (list 1 2 3))` is `(list 'a 1 2 3 1 'a 2 3 1 2 'a 3 1 2 3 'a)`, but instead my list keeps terminating.

I've been able to create this function using a 3rd parameter "position" where I do recursion on that parameter, but that botches my main function. Is there anyway to create this helper function with only two parameters? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert-everywhere procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125784/insert-everywhere-procedure)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez the output requested here is different from there. so not a duplicate, though closely related indeed.

Comment: @WillNess I don't know that they need to be _exact_ duplicates.  After all, the tough part here is generating the sublists, right?  If you can create `l == ((a 1 2 3) (1 a 2 3) (1 2 a 3) (1 2 3 a))`, then `(a 1 2 3 1 a 2 3 1 2 a 3 1 2 3 a)` is just an `(apply append l)` away…

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor actually, in one way of producing the result (mine), the difficulty *is* in deciding on how and when exactly *the appending* is to be performed. This way is also the closest to the original OP code in its approach, so it is *this* (appending, that is) that they were struggling with, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
(define (insert x index xs)
    (cond ((= index 0) (cons x xs))
          (else (cons (car xs) (insert x (- index 1) (cdr xs))))))

(define (range from to)
    (cond ((> from to) empty)
          (else (cons from (range (+ from 1) to)))))

(define (insert-everywhere x xs)
    (fold-right (lambda (index ys) (append (insert x index xs) ys))
        empty (range 0 (length xs))))
```

The `insert` function allows you to insert values anywhere within a list:

```
(insert 'a 0 '(1 2 3)) => (a 1 2 3)
(insert 'a 1 '(1 2 3)) => (1 a 2 3)
(insert 'a 2 '(1 2 3)) => (1 2 a 3)
(insert 'a 3 '(1 2 3)) => (1 2 3 a)
```

The `range` function allows you to create Haskell-style list ranges:

```
(range 0 3) => (0 1 2 3)
```

The `insert-everywhere` function makes use of `insert` and `range`. It's pretty easy to understand how it works. If your implementation of scheme doesn't have the `fold-right` function (e.g. mzscheme) then you can define it as follows:

```
(define (fold-right f acc xs)
    (cond ((empty? xs) acc)
          (else (f (car xs) (fold-right f acc (cdr xs))))))
```

As the name implies the `fold-right` function folds a list from the right.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a helper function to the helper function?

```
(define (insert_everywhere elt lst)
    (define (insert_everywhere_aux elt lst)
      (cons (cons elt lst)
            (if (empty? lst)
                empty
                (map (lambda (x) (cons (first lst) x))
                     (insert_everywhere_aux elt (rest lst))))))
    (apply append (insert_everywhere_aux elt lst)))
```

We need our sublists kept separate, so that each one can be prefixed separately. If we'd *append all* prematurely, we'd lose the boundaries. So we append only once, in the very end:

```
insert a (list 1 2 3) =                             ; step-by-step illustration:
                                            ((a))   ; the base case;
                              ((a/ 3)/    (3/ a))   ; '/' signifies the consing
                 ((a/ 2 3)/  (2/ a 3)   (2/ 3 a))
   ((a/ 1 2 3)/ (1/ a 2 3) (1/ 2 a 3) (1/ 2 3 a))
   ( a  1 2 3    1  a 2 3   1  2 a 3   1  2 3 a )   ; the result
```

Testing:

```
(insert_everywhere 'a (list 1 2 3))
;Value 19: (a 1 2 3 1 a 2 3 1 2 a 3 1 2 3 a)
```

By the way this internal function is [tail recursive modulo cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons), more or less, as also seen in the illustration. This suggests it should be possible to convert it into an iterative form. [Joshua Taylor shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20333371/849891) another way, using `revappend`. Reversing the list upfront simplifies the flow in his solution (which now corresponds to building directly the result row in the illustration, from right to left, instead of "by columns" in my version):

```
(define (insert_everywhere elt lst)
  (let g ((rev (reverse lst)) 
          (q   '())
          (res '()))
    (if (null? rev) 
      (cons elt (append q res))
      (g (cdr rev) 
         (cons (car rev) q) 
         (revappend rev (cons elt (append q res)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply having 2 lists (head and tail) and *sliding* elements from one to the other:

```
(define (insert-everywhere elt lst)
  (let loop ((head null) (tail lst))      ; initialize head (empty), tail (lst)
    (append (append head (cons elt tail)) ; insert elt between head and tail
            (if (null? tail)
                null                      ; done
                (loop (append head (list (car tail))) (cdr tail)))))) ; slide


(insert-everywhere 'a (list 1 2 3))
=> '(a 1 2 3 1 a 2 3 1 2 a 3 1 2 3 a)
```

In Racket, you could also express it in a quite concise way as follows:

```
(define (insert-everywhere elt lst)
  (for/fold ((res null)) ((i (in-range (add1 (length lst)))))
    (append res (take lst i) (cons elt (drop lst i)))))
```

Comment: This is similar to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20127236/1281433) on the possible duplicate question, [Insert-everywhere procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20125784/1281433).  This solution allocates a _lot_ of extra memory though.  E.g., in (append (append ...) ...)`, you're creating a new list with the inner `(append ...)` and then copying the whole thing in the outer `(append ...)`.  My answer to the other question avoids this as much as possible.  However, I do like that this one uses Racket's `for/fold` feature.

Comment: (Although, the question isn't tagged with Racket, so it might not be applicable for the OP.)

Comment: I take at least some of that first comment back;  I'd missed the point that in this question, all the sublists are supposed to be appended together. That means that some of the copying issues will be a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

This has a lot in common with [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20127236/1281433) to [Insert-everywhere procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20125784/1281433).  There's a procedure that seems a bit odd until you need it, and then it's incredibly useful, called `revappend`.  `(append '(a b ...) '(x y ...))` returns a list `(a b ... x y ...)`, with the elements of `(a b ...)`.  Since it's so easy to collect lists in *reverse* order while traversing a list recursively, it's useful sometimes to have `revappend`, which *reverses* the first argument, so that `(revappend '(a b ... m n) '(x y ...))` returns `(n m ... b a x y ...)`.  `revappend` is easy to implement efficiently:

```
(define (revappend list tail)
  (if (null? list)
      tail
      (revappend (rest list)
                 (list* (first list) tail))))
```

Now, a direct version of this `insert-everywhere` is straightforward.  This version isn't tail recursive, but it's pretty simple, and doesn't do any unnecessary list copying.  The idea is that we walk down the `lst` to end up with the following `rhead` and `tail`:

```
rhead   tail    (revappend rhead (list* item (append tail ...)))
------- ------- ------------------------------------------------
     () (1 2 3) (r 1 2 3 ...)
    (1) (2 3)   (1 r 2 3 ...)
  (2 1) (3)     (1 2 r 3 ...)
(3 2 1) ()      (1 2 3 r ...)
```

If you put the recursive call in the place of the `...`, then you get the result that you want:

```
(define (insert-everywhere item lst)
  (let ie ((rhead '())
           (tail lst))
    (if (null? tail)
        (revappend rhead (list item))
        (revappend rhead
                   (list* item 
                          (append tail
                                  (ie (list* (first tail) rhead)
                                      (rest tail))))))))
```

```
> (insert-everywhere 'a '(1 2 3))
'(a 1 2 3 1 a 2 3 1 2 a 3 1 2 3 a)
```

Now, this isn't tail recursive.  If you want a tail recursive (and thus iterative) version, you'll have to construct your result in a slightly backwards way, and then reverse everything at the end.  You can do this, but it does mean one extra copy of the list (unless you destructively reverse it).

```
(define (insert-everywhere item lst)
  (let ie ((rhead '())
           (tail lst)
           (result '()))
    (if (null? tail)
        (reverse (list* item (append rhead result)))
        (ie (list* (first tail) rhead)
            (rest tail)
            (revappend tail
                       (list* item
                              (append rhead
                                      result)))))))
```

```
> (insert-everywhere 'a '(1 2 3))
'(a 1 2 3 1 a 2 3 1 2 a 3 1 2 3 a)
```